# Движение мыши и\или автоматическое нажатие клавиш

Tags: java

Как на java сделать движение и\или нажатие мыши и клавиш на клавиатуре?

типа ctrl + f & \ || движение мыши лева вправо.

Comment: Читаем про `MouseAdapter` и `KeyAdapter`.

Comment: был такой класс `java.awt.Robot`, есть ли сейчас - не знаю

Comment: Сейчас использую java.awt.Robot;

Comment: Нужно подробно описывать задачу в вопросе, а не 2х словах, вот откуда мы знаем, что вы там используете? Мысли читать не умеем. Если `Robot` используете, то там все есть и `keyPress` и `mouseMove`, неужели так сложно открыть документацию и посмотреть какие методы присутствуют в классе.

Comment: Тут немного ошибся, я имел в виду что начал использовать его.